# How to make user data not show up in a query with relations

Tags: prisma

Good morning, everyone,
I have a question that I can't solve:
starting from a PROPONENT table that has the USER 1to1 as a link, I want the query to return me some profile data (PROFILE table) and some company data (COMPANY table) without giving me the user info (USER table)

Here's my query
const proponents = count > 0 ? await client.proponent.findMany({
select: {
id: true,
organizationName: true,
user: {
include:{
company: {
select:{
name: true,
phoneCompany: true,
registeredOffice: true,
vatNumber: true,
websiteUrl: true,
description: true,
shareCapital: true,
},
},
profile:{
select: {
firstName: true,
lastName: true,
},
},
},
},
},
...pagination,
where: { ...prismaWhereProponents },
}): [];

Could you help me please?

"status": "SUCCESS",
"message": "proponents fetched successfully",
"code": "200",
"data": {
"found": 6,
"took": 4,
"skipped": 0,
"sort": {
"createdAt": "desc"
},
"page": {
"current": 1,
"last": 2,
"next": 2
},
"value": [
{
"id": "59c2fe8f-05bf-4ffa-bac6-1460259eed7f",
"organizationName": "Enterprise s.n.c.",
"user": {
"createdAt": "2023-06-13T12:21:02.163Z",
"deletedAt": null,
"id": "f018ac33-fe5d-4a17-91b5-e05916c0df6e",
"email": "federico.gelmetti@recrowd.com",
"confirmedAt": "2023-06-13T12:21:02.163Z",
"applicantId": null,
"accountType": "PROPONENT",
"proponentId": "59c2fe8f-05bf-4ffa-bac6-1460259eed7f",
"statusRegister": "REGISTERED",
"consentTandC": true,
"consentNewsletter": true,
"company": {
"name": "RECROWD s.r.l.",
"phoneCompany": "+393928405731",
"registeredOffice": "Via Quaranta, 40",
"vatNumber": "101254219874321",
"websiteUrl": "www.recrowd.com",
"description": "Real Estate Crofunding",
"shareCapital": "100000"
},
"profile": {
"firstName": "Federico",
"lastName": "Gelmetti"
}
}
},
]
}
}

I don't want all this information
"createdAt": "2023-06-13T12:21:02.163Z",
"deletedAt": null,
"id": "f018ac33-fe5d-4a17-91b5-e05916c0df6e",
"email": "federico.gelmetti@recrowd.com",
"confirmedAt": "2023-06-13T12:21:02.163Z",
"applicantId": null,
"accountType": "PROPONENT",
"proponentId": "59c2fe8f-05bf-4ffa-bac6-1460259eed7f",
"statusRegister": "REGISTERED",
"consentTandC": true,
"consentNewsletter": true,

Comment: Please try to indent your code using the WYSIWYG editor.
Also try to draw entity relationship diagrams so a potential helper can understand the database model you got.
Futhermore it would be a good idea to censor personal data in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this:

```
const proponents =
  count > 0
    ? await client.proponent.findMany({
        select: {
          id: true,
          organizationName: true,
          user: {
            select: {
              //enter fields you want to fetch i.e. id 
              id: true
            },
            include: {
              company: {
                select: {
                  name: true,
                  phoneCompany: true,
                  registeredOffice: true,
                  vatNumber: true,
                  websiteUrl: true,
                  description: true,
                  shareCapital: true,
                },
              },
              profile: { select: { firstName: true, lastName: true } },
            },
          },
        },
        ...pagination,
        where: { ...prismaWhereProponents },
      })
    : [];
```